# aws_codebuild_project problem with buildspec from S3

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

When creating a build project (in AWS CodeBuild) and setting up the buildspec file to use a path from s3 (ARN) in the source section, it creates the project and puts the ARN as an inline command and not as the path for the file.
Does anyone know why this is and how to fix this?

Comment: Please share your Terraform code to understand this better. This behaviour is not noticed when creating the project from AWS Console or CLI.

Comment: resource "aws_codebuild_project" "test" {
name = "test"
description = "test"
build_timeout = "60"
service_role = aws_iam_role.test

artifacts {
type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
}

environment {
compute_type = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
image = "aws/codebuild/standard:1.0"
type = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
}

source {
type = "GITHUB"
location = "https://github.com/path-to-ptoject.git"
git_clone_depth = 5
buildspec = "arn:aws:path/to/buildspec.yml"
}
source_version = "master"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just seems to be a quirk, but there is no problem executing the CodeBuild project when the buildspec is hosted in S3. I checked and confirmed the buildspec is retrieved from S3 and executed as normal. Just run your project and confirm, you do not need to "fix" anything.

I tested with the following buildspec, similar to what you shared:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "test" {
  name          = "test-from-tf"
  description   = "test from terraform"
  build_timeout = "60"
  service_role  = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/codebuild-al2-service-role"
  artifacts { type = "NO_ARTIFACTS" }
  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/standard:1.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
  }
  source {
    type            = "GITHUB"
    location        = "https://github.com/shariqmus/eb-python.git"
    git_clone_depth = 5
    buildspec       = "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/buildspec.yml"
  }
  source_version = "master"
}
```

Note that you can also place the actual buildspec commands in the 'source > buildspec' parameter in TF file, probably the reason S3 URI shows as part of buildspec source.